# Insert/Add data into Data Extension Using AMP Script - Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: forms, ampscript

I have a requirement where, I should send email with a form(first name, Last Name, email ID and Mobile number and Submit button) to all the users in subscribers list. In return i need to capture the data into a new data extension once after the users fill the form and click the submit button.

how to achieve it using amp script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AMPScript:

[InsertDE](https://ampscript.guide/insertde/)

Note that AMPScript can be executed ONLY within Marketing Cloud Cloudpages

You can also use the MC Endpoints:

[Async Insert Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.htm)

In this case, you need to do some setup in MC in order to generate the auth token and send the request to this endpoint.

A little late, but just in case and for the future cases. Regards.